# Removing Polygons With a Specific Size

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, remove

How can I remove small polygons from a raster data set? I know that they aren't technically polygons, but I convert the rasters to polygons. The problem is that I want to focus on a specific polygon that is large and there are many small polygons surrounding it. I want the small polygons out. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what is the software are you using?

Comment: I'm using arcmap 10.2

Comment: What is the projection are you using? Do you want to delete the polygons?

Comment: I'm using Albers. Asia South Albers Equal Area Conic to be exact.

Comment: Perhaps ArcGIS has a sieve tool like this http://www.gdal.org/gdal_sieve.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a new field named area with type double, then right-click the field name, go to calculate geometry. In the property field, select area and choose meter square as units. Then go to Select by Attribute and select the areas that is more than the threshold area and save the selected polygons into a new shapefile.

Comment: Thank you ahmadhanb! That worked great. Learned that it was pretty basic stuff too. I'm new at this and that was very helpful.